# How to convert UTC time to Browser local time zone?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert UTC time to client browser time zone.

I am using below code

```
var utcDate = '08-Aug-17 10:12:29 AM' + ' UTC';
var date = new Date(utcDate);
```

Output: `Tue Aug 08 2017 15:42:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Expected output: `08-Aug-2017 3:42 PM`

How can I format the date in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    function formatDate(date) {
      var monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
        "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
        "Novr", "Dec"
      ];

      var day = date.getDate();
      var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var tim =  date.getHours() + ":"  
                               +date.getMinutes();
     function tConvert (time) {
     time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) 
    if (time.length > 1) 
     { 
      time = time.slice (1);  
      time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; 
      time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12;
     }
  return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
}
  return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year +' '+tConvert (tim); ;
    }

    console.log(formatDate(new Date()));  // show current date-time in console
```

Comment: Output is '8 Aug 2017 16:7' And I want Output :- 8 Aug 2017 4:7 PM

Comment: now try it @AshutoshBodake

Comment: Works perfectly @Nithin

Answer (score 1):

for this, you have to use [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) 
using momentJS you can do it by following way

```
var utcDate = '08-Aug-17 10:12:29 AM' + ' UTC';
console.log(moment(utcDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment library to lot of date time related issues arise in your applications.

```
moment.utc('Your UTC time here').locale("your culture here").format('llll')
```

[Download momentJs here](https://momentjs.com/)